# How to make XML.Node(....) path dynamic in SQL Server instead of string literal

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a query whose XML structure is different based of its entity type.
XML is stored in SQL Server table, additional column will have the path which will help to know where is the Identity element[Id] in XML.

`updatedXML.xmlentity` has the XML and `/Message/InfoList/Info/Id` is stored in `updatedXML.entityIdPath`.

How to use `updatedXML.entityIdPath` in `XML.nodes()` function so that single query pulls the entityid of each xml stored in table with xml.nodes?

Sample Query, with path as string literal in nodes function.

```
select X.E.value('.','bigint') As EntityId 
from updatedXML.xmlentity.nodes('/Message/InfoList/Info/Id') as X(E))
```

Table having XML storage with few metadata as individual column.

[image: Table having XML entity in it]

Adding only two for sample XML structures.

Below image has XML structure in table updatedXML
 - entityIdPath is *Message/InfoList/Info/Id*
 - entityType  is 1

[image]

Below image has XML structure in table updatedXML
 - entityIdPath is *Message/Customers/Info/CustId*
 - entityType  is 2

[image]

Both XML structures are diffrent, likewise there are many XML structures different from each other. To spot the identity of each XML, path is stored in entityIdPath.

Comment: post here table structure entityid and XML column with data

Comment: Question updated with potential table structure and structure of XML data stored in it.

Comment: Seems there is no way other than literal string path in SQL. I started using dynamic sql with sp_executesql and user defined tabel type to manage this as this moment

Comment: No man the one way is loop and pass sql variable to XML and get value but it will one value each time so i don't want to go with another way is might be OUTER APPLY let's look into it if i got success i will post here :) just post here your expected output also

Comment: sql:variable can be used to look local node name, but when need to go deeper then this is not helpful. If I understand then you mean to loop each node with sql:variable, a kind of recursive query with CTE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the SP I have created to get it working.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[QueryXMLWithPath]
    @xml XML,
    @xmlPath varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @ParmDefinition nvarchar(505)  = N'@d_xml XML';
    declare @tsql nvarchar(max)= '
    select X.E.value(''.'',''bigint'') As EntityId 
    from @d_xml.nodes('''+ @xmlPath +''') as X(E) 
    '
EXECUTE sp_executesql @tsql,@ParmDefinition,  @d_xml = @xml
END
GO
```

Here is the sample how to use it.

```
DECLARE @XMLEntityId TABLE
(
EntityId BIGINT
) 

INSERT INTO @XMLEntityId(EntityId)
EXECUTE QueryXmlWithpath @MessageBody,@SubEntityIdPath
```

Note:

1. UDF can not be used as EXEC SP_ can not be called within, that is due to restriction by SQL.
2. Recursive TSQL with CTE can be other option with UDF but that
   gives more read counts and CPU time too.